# Working with multiple classes in vuejs2 at same page

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Below is my code.

Vue Code =>

```
new Vue({
    el:'.validation',
    data:{
        message:'tet',
        search_path:'',
        change_id:null,
    }
});
```

Laravel blade file =>

```
<div class='validation'>
    @{{message}}
</div>
<div class='validation'>
    @{{message}}
</div>
<div class='validation'>
    @{{message}}
</div>
<div class='validation'>
    @{{message}}
</div>
```

Now at first div its working and i get the result correctly but other successive div's i don't get results.
So my question is how to use new vue at multiple places in laravel blade with same class thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to wrap the classes in an ID like below:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class='validation'>
      @{{message}}
  </div>
  <div class='validation'>
      @{{message}}
  </div>
  <div class='validation'>
      @{{message}}
  </div>
  <div class='validation'>
      @{{message}}
  </div>
</div>

new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        message:'tet',
        search_path:'',
        change_id:null,
    }
});
```

If this isn't what you're trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962443/vue-instance-using-classes) answer could help.